# Shared Folder Students

Tags: shared-folders

So I need to implement this for my parent's students. He is a teacher in a certain college.

He needs a web interface or say email to specific ID with attachment that stores the attachment in an online folder. Say 5 classes of 100+ students, if they all email or upload the files to certain mail ids or links they get stored in the same folder (separated by class, for example).

Once they have submitted they can neither see their or anybody else's submission.

How is that possible?
My initial research gave me hostedftp.com (website plugin seems great). 
Any other suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest/easiest way to set something like this up would be through IFTTT (If This Then That) at http://ifttt.com  while tied to his Gmail account. Have students email his Gmail account, and create a recipe in IFTTT to store all attachments to a Google Drive folder. If he often receives attachments from people who weren't students, those would save in the Gmail folder too, so he may want to create a new Gmail account just for this purpose.

Comment: Yes! he will definitely need a new gmail account but this is obviously better than purchasing something. Great answer.